# Images not shown while running the JAR created by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have my images folder inside source folder in my Eclipse IDE

After exporting the application into a runnable JAR, I run it through command prompt, but it does not display any images that I have used. When I run it through Eclipse, images are displayed.

And when I copy the source/images folder to where my executable JAR is, then it shows images, but I want my images also to be in JAR itself.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are the images inside the jar?

Comment: How are you reading the images?

Comment: This is a very common problem related to how you reference the resources in your application. Please add your image/resource loading code to the question.

Comment: @adarshr -I am using images like this -frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/Images/Icon.jpg"))

Comment: You should really use @Himanshu's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

public BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName){

```
BufferedImage buff = null;
try {
    buff = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return buff;
```

}

Comment: Be aware that `fileName` actually is the path name in the class path, in our case inside the jar. So use "/resources/icons/app.png" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Your images should NOT be in your source folder. You should hold them separate in another folder (assets or ressources or images or so).

To include the folder in your jar, I highly suggest using ANT script (or maven) to generate your jar. Its much more flexible. It takes a bit to get the grasp on it, but there are a lot of examples and tutorials around and I think its definitely worth it.